# How can I import urlparse in Python on centOS?

Tags: python, linux, centos, urllib

I've been working on a Python web crawler, and have got to the stage where I am configuring a Linux box (centOS) for it to run on.

Everything works fine locally, however, when I try to run the script on the server, I get the error "cannot import name urlparse". The relevant imports are as follows;

```
import urllib.request

from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib.robotparser
```

I've tried altering them on the server version but to no avail. urllib.request is installed and works fine.

Trying to import "urllib.request" on its own fails with "No module named request" and needed changing to "import urllib".

I also get a similar issue with the robotparser module.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

(I apologise if this question should actually have been under server administration).

Comment: What version of python are you running on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have python 2 installed, instead of python 3.  I think the urllib names are different between the two versions.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html is the python 2 version

`python -V` will give the version number

Comment: The server is on Python 2.* whilst the code was using 3.3. I'll update the server, and that should be it. Thanks!